# PFQuery number... from a current user

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfquery

Sorry I'm a beginner at objective C and coding in general.
I have a class name called "user" and a column called sneezes which is a number. Im trying to get the current users number of sneezes in a PFQuery but i cant seem to find out how and don't know where to start. 
I did look at and tried the documentation of PfQuery and the tutorials. 
I think i need to use whereKey: equalTo:  ?

Comment: if you are using PFUser, then you need not do PFQuery. You can just get it by handsome guy's code.

Answer (score 0):

```
int sneezes = [[PFUser currentUser][@"sneezes"] intValue];
```

When logged in, [PFUser currentUser] always gives you the user object. Adding [@"sneezes"] is the literal way of doing this:

```
int sneezes = [[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"sneezes"] intValue];
```

Comment: Gonna need to add intValue to those, like this: `[[PFUser currentUser][@"sneezes"] intValue];` You have to save as `NSNumber`, you can't store a regular int like that.

Comment: Is this in a PFQuery or can i just do the '[int sneezes = [[PFUser currentUser][@"sneezes"] intValue];'@Logan @Handsomeguy

Comment: You don't query for the current user. It is always available with [PFUser currentUser].